# Whatever I try, I can't install Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, usb, installation, bios, iso-image

## TL:DR:

Have a pretty modern, but already an old laptop. Some time ago it had Windows 10 x64, which I deleted. Then I installed Ubuntu 20.04. 
Now I've deleted it as well and want to install Windows XP using USB, but it doesn't work at all!
And now for those who want to help me:
What did I do (on my host machine):

1. Downloaded the ISO file from [this](https://dl.malwat.ch/windows) site (that's the only ISO which was workable) (Windows XP x64 SP2) (also may be labeled as Windows XP (x64))
2. Installed `WinSetupFromUsb 1.9`
3. Installed UltraISO
4. Mounted the ISO into CD-diskdrive using UltraISO
5. Inserted the USB-drive SiliconPower 8GB
6. Opened WinSetupFromUsb
7. Selected my USB
8. Opened Bootice
9. Opened Parts Manage
10. Formatted the partition in FAT32 (important! When formatting in NTFS, BIOS don't see the USB)
11. Left Parts Manage, Bootice
12. Selected Windows 2000/XP/2003
13. Selected my CD-diskdrive as the resource
14. Clicked GO
15. Waited until the end and removed the USB
16. Inserted into the laptop (DIGMA)
17. Opened BIOS (Aptio Setup Utility - Copyright (C) 2017 American Megatrends, Inc.)
18. Selected Save & Exit
19. Selected UEFI: UFD 2.0 Silicon-Power8G, Partition 1

It should've started the setup, but it only starts a black screen, then restarts. Tried to change priorities and set the USB at first, but it just comes to the next priority.
Please help!

BIOS STRUCTURE:

```
Main:

BIOS Information
BIOS Vendor American Megatrends
System Serial Number
Core Version 5.011
Compliancy UEFI 2.4; PI 1.3
Project Version                    it doesn't matter
Build Date and Time                it doesn't matter

CPU Configuration Intel(R) ______________

Memory Information
Total Memory                       2048 MB (DDR3)

GOP Information
Intel(R) GOP Driver                it doesn't matter

TXE Information
Sec RC Version                     it doesn't matter
TXE FW Version                     it doesn't matter

System Language                    [English] Options: English

System Date                        date
System Time                        time

=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=

Boot:


Boot Configuration
Setup Prompt Timeout               [0] (You can select any in range 0-65535)
Bootup NumLock State               [Off] Options: Off, On

Quiet Boot                         [Disabled] Options: Disabled, Enabled
Fast Boot                          [Disabled] Options: Disabled, Enabled
                                   When selecting Enabled, these occur:
VGA Support                        [EFI Driver]
USB Support                        [Full Initial] Options: Disabled, Full Initial, Partial Initial
PS2 Devices Support                [Enabled] Options: Disabled, Enabled
NetWork Stack Driver Support       [Enabled] Options: Disabled, Enabled

Boot Option Priorities
Boot Option #1 [My USB]
Boot Option #2 [Built-in EFI Shell]
Boot Option #3 [ubuntu (didn't finish the deleting yet)]

=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=

Save & Exit:


Save Changes and Exit
Discard Changes and Exit
Save Changes and Reset
Discard Changes and Reset

Save Options
Save Changes
Discard Changes

Restore Defaults
Save as User Defaults
Restore User Defaults

Boot Override
UEFI: Built-in EFI Shell
UEFI: UFD 2.0 Silicon-Power8G, Partition 1
ubuntu

Launch EFI Shell from filesystem device

=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=

Version 2.17.1249. Copyright (C) 2017 American Megatrends, Inc.
```

Comment: You cannot install Win_XP from USB without serious modification of installation source. Because the install package does not have USB drivers by default to support installation. As soon as the system switches to reboot from initial Windows, the boot drive will be lost.Different media formats cannot help here.

Comment: Good luck finding XP drivers for that newer hardware.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download Rufus it more better as it have fixes for old pcs than Bootice

https://github.com/pbatard/rufus/releases/download/v3.11/rufus-3.11.exe

Looks you have made mistake in  **Partition Scheme** or **Target system** in Bootice while making bootable USD

For Old PC select the settings I have shown but

1.If you have made partitions as **GPT** before then only choose **GPT** in partition scheme or leave as **MBR**

2.File system will be default according to OS so dont change it at 1st

If along with added fixes for old bios option by rufus the usb dont boot
you can  try changing partition scheme option to other fat32 with same settings leaving
rest settings as it is

But 1st try the fixes for OLD pcs instead changing partition scheme

[image]

Comment: My BIOS just doesn't see the NTFS-formatted drives.

Comment: Okay keep rest settings change only file system to fat32

Comment: Not possible for Windows XP, Vista or 7 for my computer, but as I understood it's only because of my BIOS and age of laptop. Thanks, I installed Windows 8!

Comment: Could do do install windows 8 by making USB file system** fat32 or ntfs** and what was file system default value on your pc **ntfs or fat32** while making bootable windows 8 usb in rufus?

Comment: FAT32. My laptop is incompatible with old versions of Windows so that's fine

Comment: So I think the old PC fixes rufus contributed to successful windows 8 installation otherwise fat32 windows 8 may not be installed